# Creating abstraction over a class locate in external library

Tags: c#

The c# project I am working on make references to a "Product" concrete type that resides in an external class libray. "Product" class does not implement any interface.

I would like to create an "IProduct" interface base on "Product" and use this interface code, so I can program against an interface, not an implementation.

As I still want to keep using "Product" type, what could be a good pattern to let my code knows "Product" implements "IProduct"?

As "Product" resides in an external library, I cannnot alter its declaration (i.e Procut: IProduct).

The class has also no public constructor, so I guess extending it is not an option.

What is a good solution pattern for this scenario? A wrapper?

Thank you.

Comment: You have discussed the types: `Product`, `Produt`, `Prodcut`, `Procuct`, and `Procut`. Are these all different, or meant to be the same?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use the Adapter pattern.

So you can so something like the below:

```
public class Product 
{
    // Your Product Class
}

public class MyProduct : Product,  IProduct
{

}
```

Where the `MyProduct` class implements the interface but also has all of the public and protected methods/properties available from the `Product` class. This allows you to extend the original class without modification to the `Product` class which follows the Open/Close principle.

You can read more about this here: https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-daily-design-pattern-adapter/

Comment: Can I do this if Product does not expose a public constructor?

Comment: as long as the Product class is not declared as sealed, you should be able to derive from it

Comment: it is not sealed, but I think if it has no public constructor, I will get the error "'Product' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments". In my case Product has no other public constructor overload.

Comment: check if Product has a private constructor

Comment: all constructor overloads are internal.